# Locating the headers that I need to build a custom tflite for lstm

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I tried to convert my tf.keras model to tflite, but I met with some missing operators. the TOCO output contains these strings -- *I've tried to make then unique, rather than dumping the whole thing*:

```
Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_4/TensorArray
Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_4/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3
Converting unsupported operation: Enter
Converting unsupported operation: LoopCond
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_4/while/LoopCond
Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
Converting unsupported operation: ReadVariableOp
Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_4/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3
Converting unsupported operation: Exit
Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_4/TensorArrayStack/TensorArraySizeV3
Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_5/TensorArray
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_5/TensorArray_1
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_5/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_5/while/LoopCond
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_5/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_5/TensorArrayStack/TensorArraySizeV3
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_6/TensorArray
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_6/TensorArray_1
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_6/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_6/while/LoopCond
Op node missing output type attribute: lstm_6/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3
```

So I am reading about how to support those operations -- apparently the method is to do a custom build with those operations in place. There's [a promising looking guide](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/compiling-a-tensorflow-lite-build-with-custom-operations-cf6330ee30e2) for this, but he doesn't really specify how he located which headers he needed.

Can you help me locate the headers I will need to include ?

### updates

I've located the ... apparently just 1 file for TensorArrayV3: `tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native/tensor_array_ops.h`

This file makes use of protobufs that are not compiled by default (the raw *host_compute_metadata.proto* is present, but not the *.pb.h*/*.pb.cc* files). I am having trouble understanding the build system well enough to know where to look to build these... I downloaded my own protoc and can compile it, but I'm not sure that I am doing it right and it references two more .proto files that also are not compiled to *.pb.**, namely `types.proto` and `tensor_shape.proto` from core. Compiling core does not generate them.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?